# Convert pandas DataFrame to a nested dict

Tags: python, pandas

I'm Looking for a generic way of turning a DataFrame to a nested dictionary

This is a sample data frame

```
    name    v1  v2  v3
0   A       A1  A11 1
1   A       A2  A12 2
2   B       B1  B12 3
3   C       C1  C11 4
4   B       B2  B21 5
5   A       A2  A21 6
```

The number of columns may differ and so does the column names.

like this :

```
{
'A' : { 
    'A1' : { 'A11' : 1 }
    'A2' : { 'A12' : 2 , 'A21' : 6 }} , 
'B' : { 
    'B1' : { 'B12' : 3 } } , 
'C' : { 
    'C1' : { 'C11' : 4}}
}
```

What is best way to achieve this ?

closest I got was with the `zip` function but haven't managed to make it work for more then one level (two columns).

Comment: There is a question that's basically this backwards here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't understand why there isn't a `B2` in your dict.  I'm also not sure what you want to happen in the case of repeated column values (every one except the last, I mean.)  Assuming the first is an oversight, we could use recursion:

```
def recur_dictify(frame):
    if len(frame.columns) == 1:
        if frame.values.size == 1: return frame.values[0][0]
        return frame.values.squeeze()
    grouped = frame.groupby(frame.columns[0])
    d = {k: recur_dictify(g.ix[:,1:]) for k,g in grouped}
    return d
```

which produces

```
>>> df
  name  v1   v2  v3
0    A  A1  A11   1
1    A  A2  A12   2
2    B  B1  B12   3
3    C  C1  C11   4
4    B  B2  B21   5
5    A  A2  A21   6
>>> pprint.pprint(recur_dictify(df))
{'A': {'A1': {'A11': 1}, 'A2': {'A12': 2, 'A21': 6}},
 'B': {'B1': {'B12': 3}, 'B2': {'B21': 5}},
 'C': {'C1': {'C11': 4}}}
```

It might be simpler to use a non-pandas approach, though:

```
def retro_dictify(frame):
    d = {}
    for row in frame.values:
        here = d
        for elem in row[:-2]:
            if elem not in here:
                here[elem] = {}
            here = here[elem]
        here[row[-2]] = row[-1]
    return d
```

Comment: Now replace `g.ix` with `g.iloc`

Answer (score 7):

You can reconstruct your dictionary as easy as follows

```
result = {}
for lst in df.values:
    leaf = result
    for path in lst[:-2]:
       leaf = leaf.setdefault(path, {})
    leaf.setdefault(lst[-2], list()).append(lst[-1])

>>> result
{'A': {'A1': {'A11': [1]}, 'A2': {'A21': [6], 'A12': [2]}}, 'C': {'C1': {'C11': [4]}}, 'B':  {'B1': {'B12': [3]}, 'B2': {'B21': [5]}}}
```

If you're sure your leafs won't overlap, replace last line

```
    leaf.setdefault(lst[-2], list()).append(lst[-1])
```

with

```
    leaf[lst[-2]] = lst[-1]
```

to get output you desired:

```
>>> result
{'A': {'A1': {'A11': 1}, 'A2': {'A21': 6, 'A12': 2}}, 'C': {'C1': {'C11': 4}}, 'B': {'B1': {'B12': 3}, 'B2': {'B21': 5}}}
```

Sample data used for tests:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['A','A','B','C','B','A'],
          'v1': ['A1','A2','B1','C1','B2','A2'],
          'v2': ['A11','A12','B12','C11','B21','A21'],
          'v3': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict) as their are some options that you can pass to get the output in several different forms.

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
  name  v1   v2  v3
0    A  A1  A11   1
1    A  A2  A12   2
2    B  B1  B12   3
3    C  C1  C11   4
4    B  B2  B21   5
5    A  A2  A21   6

In [6]: df.to_dict()
Out[6]: 
{'name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'B', 5: 'A'},
 'v1': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'B1', 3: 'C1', 4: 'B2', 5: 'A2'},
 'v2': {0: 'A11', 1: 'A12', 2: 'B12', 3: 'C11', 4: 'B21', 5: 'A21'},
 'v3': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}}
```

Here is a way to create a json format, then literally eval it to create an actual dict

```
In [11]: import ast

In [15]: ast.literal_eval(df.to_json(orient='values'))
Out[15]: 
[['A', 'A1', 'A11', 1],
 ['A', 'A2', 'A12', 2],
 ['B', 'B1', 'B12', 3],
 ['C', 'C1', 'C11', 4],
 ['B', 'B2', 'B21', 5],
 ['A', 'A2', 'A21', 6]]
```

Comment: hey @Jeff, i tried all the options + about 10 posts about similar topics in SO, still haven't managed to get the desired output.

Comment: you can also try ``df.to_json()``, again has various options

Comment: That's a good tip, `to_json(orient="values")` gives me the paths, now i need to figure how to build a dict from it.

Comment: see above how to do that!

Comment: Why you used ast ? to_json gives the same output.

Comment: ast.literal_eval gives you an actual object, e.g. a list, (and not a string)

Comment: `map(list, df.values) == ast.literal_eval(df.to_json(orient='values'))` evals to `True`

Answer (score 1):

```
data.groupby(by='name', sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Should help and is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using defaultdict

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'B', 5: 'A'},
 'v1': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'B1', 3: 'C1', 4: 'B2', 5: 'A2'},
 'v2': {0: 'A11', 1: 'A12', 2: 'B12', 3: 'C11', 4: 'B21', 5: 'A21'},
 'v3': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}})


output = defaultdict(dict)

for lst in df.values:
    try:
        output[lst[0]][lst[1]].update({lst[2]:lst[3]})
    except KeyError:
        output[lst[0]][lst[1]] = {}
    finally:
        output[lst[0]][lst[1]].update({lst[2]:lst[3]})

output
```

or:

```
output = defaultdict(dict)

for row in df.values:

    item1,item2 = row[0:2]

    if output.get(item1, {}).get(item2) == None:
        output[item1][item2] = {}

    output[item1][item2].update({row[2]:row[3]})
```