# Pandas DataFrame Combine Certain Columns in Nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

Let's say you have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
A1a  A1b   A2a    A2b   …   B1a …
0.25 0.75  0.10   0.5       1   
…    …     …      …         …
```

And you want to output a JSON list of objects (one object for each row) that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        A: {
            1: {
                a: 0.25,
                b: 0.75
            },
            2: {
                a: 0.1,
                b: 0.5,
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        B: {
            1: {
                a: 1
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

What's the best way to do this?

There are obviously a lot of pandas/nested JSON questions on here, but I think this is different because I'm trying to nest specific columns within the same row, rather than grouping rows that have the same values in columns (like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798112/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-a-nested-dict)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you link the page , I will borrow the [`recur_dictify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19900276/7964527) function from the accepted answer in that link

```
#make your df columns become multiple index 
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns.map(list).map(tuple))

      A
      1          2
      a     b    a    b
0  0.25  0.75  0.1  0.5

#Then we apply the function
recur_dictify(df.T.reset_index())

{'A': {'1': {'a': 0.25, 'b': 0.75}, '2': {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.5}}}
```

Comment: This is really clean, very nice!