# how to convert dataframe to dict with nestes array in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe sales_df:

```
id  year    month   total_sales
0   2020    1       200
1   2019    12      866474119
1   2019    10      555
1   2019    11      13073203
1   2020    2       5255259695
1   2020    1       13622027370
```

From this, I want to make a dictionnary, as follow:

```
[
  {
    "2020": {
      "1": "200"
    },
    "id": "0"
  },
  {
    "2019": {
      "10": "555",
      "11": "13073203",
      "12": "866474119"
    },
    "2020": {
      "1": "13553473101",
      "2": "6000"
    },
    "id": "1"
  }
]
```

i convert df to pandas achchive the output i want know without convert how to achive that

Comment: I think even in pyspark your going to have to use collect() to driver node, and then use asDict() on your list of rows. doing it the pandas way might your best bet. i could be wrong..

Comment: you can refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798112/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-a-nested-dict

Comment: d = {k: recur_dictify(g.ix[:,1:]) for k,g in grouped}
                                        ^
i am geting SyntaxError: invalid syntax