# How to merge dictionaries in np.ndarray into one dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, merge

Following my question on [Convert Dataframe to Nested Dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062147/convert-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary-in-python/63062548?noredirect=1#comment111518087_63062548), I have been trying to convert a Pandas dataframe into a nested dictionary.

Current challenge is merging multiple dictionaries inside a np.ndarray into one.

1. My current output `dkl` is

   ```
   array([{0.7863340563991272: 0.0002639915522703274},
          {0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}], dtype=object)
   ```

   Which when checked for `type` results `numpy.ndarray`.
2. I need to get `dkl` to be

   ```
   {0.7863340563991272: 0.0002639915522703274,
    0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}
   ```

I am failing to get the desired results. I tried to turn `dkl` into a `l1 = list(dkl)`, resulting in:

```
[{0.7863340563991272: 0.0002639915522703274},
 {0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}]
```

I am now able to get the two elements of the list above which are `it1 = {0.7863340563991272: 0.0002639915522703274}` and `it2 = {0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}`, which I am trying to merge into one dictionary. I tried:

```
 dict(it1.items() + it2.items())
```

resulting in:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-4422fd31b345> in <module>
----> 1 dict(it1.items() + it2.items())

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'
```

In short, I need to get from **1** to **2**.
Update: Ref to mention in comments that this shape of output is not possible in dict, I am tyring to understand how this comes about: [image]

Reason being that I have a dataset I need to replicate that is structured as shown above in my desired output, and if not possible with dict, I have no idea how it's been created...

Comment: That is not possible, you can't have a dictionary where the same key appears twice with different values.

Comment: In general, this should answer your question: [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python-taking-union-o)

Comment: P.S. Perhaps you should pick smaller numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4 to demonstrate with.

Comment: In earlier Python versions, `dict.items()` returned a list, which you could concatenate  using the `+` operator. Presumably you were following some advice which was only valid for an older Python version.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I saw this in another post that it is not possible, so then how is it If I type in my desired output, and query the 'type' , it says 'dict' ? will show example in edited question.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [10]: dkl=np.array([{0.7863340563991272: 0.0002639915522703274}, 
    ...:        {0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}], dtype=object)                          
In [11]: dkl                                                                                         
Out[11]: 
array([{0.7863340563991272: 0.0002639915522703274},
       {0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}], dtype=object)
```

An object dtype array is for (most) practical purposes a list.  Your `list(dkl)` does that explicitly, or `tolist()`:

```
In [12]: alist = dkl.tolist()                                                                        
In [13]: alist                                                                                       
Out[13]: 
[{0.7863340563991272: 0.0002639915522703274},
 {0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}]
```

One way way to merge dictionaries is `update`:

```
In [14]: d1 = alist[0]                                                                               
In [15]: for d in alist[1:]: d1.update(d)                                                            
In [16]: d1                                                                                          
Out[16]: {0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}
```

In your case both have the same key, so the result is last dictionary in the list.

```
{0.7863340563991272: 0.0002639915522703274,
 0.7863340563991272: 0.0006863780359028511}
```

is impossible since keys of a dictionary are unique.

Other possible mergers include adding values with matching keys, or a list with values.  I'm not sure I should spend time on those since you don't seem to know what you really need.

You try adding the `items`; using the py3 list(items), we get a list of lists of tuples:

```
In [20]: [list(d.items()) for d in dkl]                                                              
Out[20]: 
[[(0.7863340563991272, 0.0002639915522703274)],
 [(0.7863340563991272, 0.0006863780359028511)]]
```

where the tuples contain the key and value.  But apart from concatenating I don't know what you want to do with those tuples.

In sum, you have a bunch of dictionaries, which may or may not have matching keys.  There's nothing special, numpy-wise here.

Comment: thanks for your response, so the basic idea is that there is no way to create in python the dataset in the shape I'm looking for. Aim for this is: A model ingests data that looks like this, but has not been provided with documentation, so I need to reverse identify how its input (my desired output) been created from a base panda dataframe. The data when converted from dataframe to nested dictionary looks like what I've shared as desired output. Thus my confusion.