# How to create dictionary with multiple column from excel in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

I want to create a dictionary from the values imported from the excel file using python, the excel columns file looks like this:

| University | Year |
| --- | --- |
| IUB | 2013 |
| IUB | 2013 |
| IUB | 2013 |
| IUB | 2014 |
| IUB | 2015 |
| BZU | 2013 |
| BZU | 2013 |
| BZU | 2014 |
| UCP | 2016 |
| UCP | 2016 |
| UCP | 2013 |
| UCP | 2014 |

The output should look like this :

```
         'IUB': {'2013': '3', '2014': '1', '2015': '1'}, 
         'BZU': {'2013': '2', '2014': '1'}, 
         'UCP': {'2013': '1', '2014': '1', '2016': '2'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas to read your Excel file. Then use `groupby` ('University, 'Year') and `agg` to calculate the count for each University/Year.

Format your DataFrame with `pivot` then export to dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("your_excel_file.xlsx")
df['count'] = 0
df = df.groupby(['University', 'Year'], as_index=False)['count'].agg('count')
df = df.pivot(index="Year", columns="University", values="count")
output = df.to_dict()
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'BZU': {2013: 2.0, 2014: 1.0, 2015: nan, 2016: nan}, 'IUB': {2013: 3.0, 2014: 1.0, 2015: 1.0, 2016: nan}, 'UCP': {2013: 1.0, 2014: 1.0, 2015: nan, 2016: 2.0}}
```

You'll have to remove `nan` values manually if necessary:

```
for uni, year in output.items():
   for y, count in list(year.items()):
      if pd.isna(count):
         del year[y]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'BZU': {2013: 2.0, 2014: 1.0}, 'IUB': {2013: 3.0, 2014: 1.0, 2015: 1.0}, 'UCP': {2013: 1.0, 2014: 1.0, 2016: 2.0}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer. Can you please tell me what should I have to do If I have one additional column and I want to make It key also.

Comment: It depends on where you want your new key. Feel free to open a new question and ask exactly what you need with column content and position of the key!

Comment: {'BZU': {'IT' : {2013: 1.0, 2014: 1.0, 2015: nan, 2016: 2.0}}} {'UCP': {'CS': {2013: 1.0, 2014: 1.0, 2015: nan, 2016: 2.0}}}. Can you please help me in Making this type of list as I am not able to open a new question.

Comment: It's not straight-forward to create a nested dict from a DataFrame but the question has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798112/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-a-nested-dict