# How to convert the dictionary into 2D table form in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm new to Pandas,

I want to know how to convert that kind of dictionary into DataFrame as tabular form.

This problem is similar to my previous problem,

But I couldn't think of how to fix it.

#### Expected format

[image]

#### Dictionary

```
[{'2009': [{'Actual': '(0.2)'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'}]},
 {'2010': [{'Actual': '2.8'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'}]},
 {'2011': [{'Actual': '2.0'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'}]},
 {'2012': [{'Actual': '2.0'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'}]},
 {'2013': [{'Actual': '2.5'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '-'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '-'}]},
 {'2014': [{'Actual': '-'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '3.0'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '3.0'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '2.8'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '2.1'}]},
 {'2015': [{'Actual': '-'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '3.5'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '3.2'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '3.0'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '2.2'}]},
 {'2016': [{'Actual': '-'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '3.4'},
           {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '3.0'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '2.5'},
           {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '2.2'}]},
 {'Longer Run': [{'Actual': '-'},
                 {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '2.4'},
                 {'Upper\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '2.3'},
                 {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Central\xa0Tendency': '2.2'},
                 {'Lower\xa0End\xa0of\xa0Range': '1.8'}]}]
```

I tried to run `pprint(pd.DataFrame(data[0]))`, but got the result is not my expectation

#### Unexpected output

```
                                                2009  \
0  [{'Actual': '(0.2)'}, {'Upper End of Range': '...
1                                                NaN
2                                                NaN
3                                                NaN
4                                                NaN
5                                                NaN
6                                                NaN
7                                                NaN
8                                                NaN

                                                2010  \
0                                                NaN
1  [{'Actual': '2.8'}, {'Upper End of Range': '-'...
2                                                NaN
3                                                NaN
4                                                NaN
5                                                NaN
6                                                NaN
7                                                NaN
```

Comment: How is this question different from your previous two questions?

Comment: I tried to run `pprint(pd.DataFrame(data[0]))`, but got the result is not my expectation

Answer (score 1):

Using your `d`:

```
pd.DataFrame({k1:{k2:v2 for vx in v1 for k2, v2 in vx.iteritems()}
              for d1 in d for k1, v1 in d1.iteritems()})
```

returns

```
                                2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 Longer Run
Actual                         (0.2)  2.8  2.0  2.0  2.5    -    -    -          -
Lower�End�of�Central�Tendency      -    -    -    -    -  2.8  3.0  2.5        2.2
Lower�End�of�Range                 -    -    -    -    -  2.1  2.2  2.2        1.8
Upper�End�of�Central�Tendency      -    -    -    -    -  3.0  3.2  3.0        2.3
Upper�End�of�Range                 -    -    -    -    -  3.0  3.5  3.4        2.4
```

Find better variable names before you implement it.