# How to convert a 3-level dictionary to a desired format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a 3-level dictionary like this:

```
data={'2016-11-28': {'area1': {'am': -0.007, 'pm': 0.008}, 'area2': {'am': 0.0, 'pm': 0.0}, 'area3': {'am': -0.01, 'pm': -0.001}},'2016-11-29':{'area1': {'am': -0.007, 'pm': 0.008}, 'area2': {'am': 0.0, 'pm': 0.0}, 'area3': {'am': -0.01, 'pm': -0.001}}}
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe, and I tried:

```
tickers=data['2016-11-28'].keys()
iterables=[tickers,['am','pm']]
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['ticker', 'time'])
frame=pd.DataFrame(data,index=index)
```

but I got

```
                2016-11-28  2016-11-29
ticker time                        
area1  am           NaN         NaN
       pm           NaN         NaN
area3  am           NaN         NaN
       pm           NaN         NaN
area2  am           NaN         NaN
       pm           NaN         NaN
```

There are no values in the dataframe, only column names and index names. What's wrong with my code? Can someone help? Thanks very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my own solution: triple for loop to force dictionary to conform to rules for hierarchical index which is `{'col1':{('row1_level0', 'row1_level1'):value}}`

Which will look like this when used

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':{('rowidx0_level0', 'rowidx0_level1'):5}})

                         col1
rowidx0_level0 rowidx0_level1     5
```

And here is the implementation

```
d = {}
for date, areas in data.items():
    d[date] = {}
    for area, times in areas.items():
        for time, value in times.items():
            d[date][(area, time)] = value 

pd.DataFrame(d)

          2016-11-28  2016-11-29
area1 am      -0.007      -0.007
      pm       0.008       0.008
area2 am       0.000       0.000
      pm       0.000       0.000
area3 am      -0.010      -0.010
      pm      -0.001      -0.001
```

And this is what the actual dictionary `d` looks like:

```
{'2016-11-28': {('area1', 'am'): -0.007,
  ('area1', 'pm'): 0.008,
  ('area2', 'am'): 0.0,
  ('area2', 'pm'): 0.0,
  ('area3', 'am'): -0.01,
  ('area3', 'pm'): -0.001},
 '2016-11-29': {('area1', 'am'): -0.007,
  ('area1', 'pm'): 0.008,
  ('area2', 'am'): 0.0,
  ('area2', 'pm'): 0.0,
  ('area3', 'am'): -0.01,
  ('area3', 'pm'): -0.001}}
```

Adopting the answer linked to from @acushner.

```
dates = []
frames = []

for date, d in data.items():
    dates.append(date)
    frames.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').stack())

pd.concat(frames, keys=dates, axis=1)

          2016-11-28  2016-11-29
area1 pm       0.008       0.008
      am      -0.007      -0.007
area2 pm       0.000       0.000
      am       0.000       0.000
area3 pm      -0.001      -0.001
      am      -0.010      -0.010
```