# Nested dictionary to pandas df

Tags: pandas, dictionary, multi-index

My first question in stackoverflow!

I have a triple nested dictionary and I want to convert it to pandas df.
The dictionary has the following structure:

```
dictionary = {'CompanyA': {'Revenue': {date1 : $1}, {date2: $2}},... 
                          {'ProfitLoss': {date1 : $0}, {date2: $1}}},
              'CompanyB': {'Revenue': {date1 : $1}, {date2: $2}},... 
                          {'ProfitLoss': {date1 : $0}, {date2: $1}}},
              'CompanyC': {'Revenue': {date1 : $1}, {date2: $2}},...
                          {'ProfitLoss': {date1 : $0}, {date2: $1}}}}
```

So far I been able to construct a df using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
```

But the results its a df with values as dictionaries like this:

```
          CompanyA          CompanyB          CompanyC
Revenue   {date1:$0,..}     {date1:$1,..}     {date1:$0,..} 
ProfitLoss{date1:$0,..}     {date1:$0,..}     {date1:$0,..}
```

I want the table to look like this:

```
                    CompanyA    CompanyB    CompanyC  
Revenue    Date1       $1          $1          $1 
           Date2       $2          $2          $2

ProfitLoss Date1       $0          $0          $0
           Date2       $1          $1          $1
```

I had tried using pd.MultiIndex.from_dict (.from_product) and change the index, with no result.  Any idea what to do next?  Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're new, but there may be an answer to a similar question, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13581730/5535114). Next time try looking for a similar question using keywords. For example, I found the one I linked by searching **"pandas nested dict"**, and that's it, the first link was the SO post!

Anyway, you need to reshape your input `dict`. You want a dict structured like this:

```
{
    'CompanyA': {
        ('Revenue', 'date1'): 1,
        ('ProfitLoss', 'date1'): 0,
    }
    ...
}
```

I would do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'CompanyA': {
        'Revenue': {
            "date1": 1,
            "date2": 2
        },
        'ProfitLoss': {
            "date1": 0,
            "date2": 1
        }
    },
    'CompanyB': {
        'Revenue': {
            "date1": 4,
            "date2": 5
        },
        'ProfitLoss': {
            "date1": 2,
            "date2": 3
        }
    }
}

# Reshape your data and pass it to `DataFrame.from_dict`
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i: {(j, k): data[i][j][k]
                                    for j in data[i] for k in data[i][j]}
                                for i in data}, orient="columns")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  CompanyA  CompanyB
ProfitLoss date1         0         2
           date2         1         3
Revenue    date1         1         4
           date2         2         5
```

**EDIT**

Using actual datetimes to respond to your comment:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

date1 = dt.datetime.now()
date2 = date1 + dt.timedelta(days=365)

data = {
    'CompanyA': {
        'Revenue': {
            date1: 1,
            date2: 2
        },
        'ProfitLoss': {
            date1: 0,
            date2: 1
        }
    },
    'CompanyB': {
        'Revenue': {
            date1: 4,
            date2: 5
        },
        'ProfitLoss': {
            date1: 2,
            date2: 3
        }
    }
}

# Reshape your data and pass it to `DataFrame.from_dict`
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i: {(j, k): data[i][j][k]
                                    for j in data[i] for k in data[i][j]}
                                for i in data}, orient="columns")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                       CompanyA  CompanyB
ProfitLoss 2018-10-08 11:19:09.006375         0         2
           2019-10-08 11:19:09.006375         1         3
Revenue    2018-10-08 11:19:09.006375         1         4
           2019-10-08 11:19:09.006375         2         5
```

Comment: Edgar, thank you for taking your time answering my question.  Following your example, I got to the same result as I got before using Pandas MultiIndex.  In both case I got the right table format but no data just NaN inside the table.  Could the date format ( datetime.date(2018, 3, 31): 1.0 ) had something to do with populating the table wrong?

Comment: @edmond-dantes, check the structure of your dictionary. I think `dictionary = {'CompanyA': {'Revenue': {date1 : $1}, {date2: $2}},... ` should be `dictionary = {'CompanyA': {'Revenue': {date1 : $1, date2: $2}},... `.

Comment: the structure of the original dictionary it's Ok, I misplaced a { }, sorry about that!  Continuing with this, it's looks like that there's a bug according to this post at GitHub.  It's exactly my problem with the dates:  [https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19993]

Comment: I will consider my question answered!