# Convert Nested Dataframe In Dict To Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen this issue [construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary). The difference is that here I consider **Nested Dataframe In Dict**.

My problem may seem to be confusing. Here's a simple example.
Nested dataframe in dict:

```
d1=pd.DataFrame({'s':[1]})
d2=pd.DataFrame({'s':[2]})
d3=pd.DataFrame({'s':[3]})
d={'a':d1,
  'b':d2,
  'c':d3}
```

What I want is a dataframe like:

```
a b c
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you dictionary contains dataframes as values, you can simply use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on the dictionary itself:

```
df = pd.concat(d, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(-1)
```

The resulting dataframe will have multiindex columns, the last line will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concat dataframes

```
dff = pd.DataFrame()
for i in list(d.keys()):
    dff = pd.concat([dff,d[i]],axis=1)

dff.columns = ["a","b","c"]
```