# nested dict into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

hi i have a python dictionary data structure like the below

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {'AMZN': [{'improv_sharpe': -4.9719673781114265e-05},
              {'stan_sharpe': 0.5995152805688786},
              {'prob_sharpe': 1.0159440451398998e-19},
              {},
              {},
              {}],
             'GOOGL': [{'improv_sharpe': 2.6114809517957284e-05},
              {'stan_sharpe': 0.16322865760123956},
              {'prob_sharpe': 6.376598832386561e-72},
              {},
              {},
              {}]})
```

how to i turn the above into the dataframe below:

```
                      AMZN                                     GOOGL
improv_sharpe': -4.9719673781114265e-05                   2.6114809517957284e-05
```

etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)

Comment: apologies i am trying the reference but i cannot seem to get it to work. @C8H10N4O2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with list and dict comprehensions as can many similar questions, but I couldn't find an exact duplicate.

If your example data is:

```
example_data = {'AMZN': [{'improv_sharpe': -4.9719673781114265e-05},
              {'stan_sharpe': 0.5995152805688786},
              {'prob_sharpe': 1.0159440451398998e-19},
              {},
              {},
              {}],
             'GOOGL': [{'improv_sharpe': 2.6114809517957284e-05},
              {'stan_sharpe': 0.16322865760123956},
              {'prob_sharpe': 6.376598832386561e-72},
              {},
              {},
              {}]
 }
```

then:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({comp_nm :     # company name is the column name
               pd.Series({  # company data is the column vector
                  k:v for d in comp_data # since your company entries are lists of length one 
                      for k,v in d.items() if d # remove empty {}'s which will throw error
                 }) 
              # each company is a dict with name as key and list of length one as value
              for comp_nm, comp_data in example_data.items() 
})
```

returns:

```
                       AMZN         GOOGL
improv_sharpe -4.971967e-05  2.611481e-05
stan_sharpe    5.995153e-01  1.632287e-01
prob_sharpe    1.015944e-19  6.376599e-72
```

You can learn more about lists, dicts, and comprehensions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Beautiful elegant code, thank you good sir, I am in your debt. I will mark the question as answered.