# How to make json parsing check code shorter or more readable?

Tags: python, json, parsing

Is there a simpler or more idiomatic way to write this?

```
def jsonToCsvPart1(fields):
    csvFormat = ''
    fields = json.loads(fields)
    for key in fields.keys() :
        tf = str(fields[key])
        mk = ''
        for idx in tf :
            if idx == '{' or idx == '}' or idx == '[' or idx == ']' :
                continue
            else :
               mk += idx
        csvFormat += (mk + ",")
    yield csvFormat
```

Comment: what type are `mk`, `idx` and `tf`?

Comment: Please make this a full working program... really that's just setting an initial value for `mk`.

Comment: @PierreD All three are strings.@tdelaney yes.

Comment: yikes -- that's a whole different question, now with the context!  I would not do it like that at all then. How deeply nested is your `fields` dict?

Comment: you should perhaps look at `pandas`. I just answered a question on how to put a deeply nested `dict` from a JSON string into a `DataFrame` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573305/faster-way-to-make-pandas-multiindex-dataframe-than-append/65573463#65573463). And `pandas` excels at many things, including writing CSV files (fast).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to manually write a json parser/ converter to csv. You're aware that Python already has tons of libraries for this, to fit almost every use-case? Unless this is a homework assignment, I wouldn't do it. See e.g. [How to parse data in JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse data in JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format)

Comment: @smci It's not homework, it's data flow from GCP. It's data processing. So I used Python, and I wrote the code about Python, and it was made too long, so I posted a question to increase readability. ):

Comment: Then why don't you use any of the many json libraries?

Comment: @smci I have already used json loads.
Because I wanted to change the json format to csv, I changed the value of json to csv (except header) string format. So, I didn't really feel the need except for json loads. also I have to put it in csv format (type : string) to load it on the table of GCP.

Comment: Then this seems to be the duplicate [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: @smci 
Thank you. :)

Comment: It seems from `csvFormat += (mk + ",")` that this code is trying to make a csv cell. If any of the interior data in `mk` contains a comma or a quote, they will not be escaped properly. It may be better to yield a list and have the `csv` module write it as a CSV row.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the grand scheme is, but you can write it in a way that will likely be faster:

Here, assuming you are building a string:

```
exclude = set(list('{}[]'))  # note: set is faster than list for membership test
mk = ''.join([idx for idx in tf if idx not in exclude])
# 61 ms on a 1M-char random string
```

```
exclude = '{}[]'  # ...but string is even faster, when so short
mk = ''.join([idx for idx in tf if idx not in exclude])
# 38 ms on a 1M-char random string
```

By the way, it will be considerably faster to achieve the same by letting the large loop (on all chars of `tf`) be done by builtin functions, and just iterate on the chars to exclude:

```
mk = tf.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
# 11.8ms on 1M chars
```

And yet faster:

```
mk = tf.translate({ord(c): None for c in '{}[]'})
# 4.5 ms on 1M chars
```

Setup (if anyone is interested to look for yet a faster way):

```
tf = ''.join(np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijk{}[]'), size=1_000_000))
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific purpose (and learning), checking specific chars in a string will work. python `set` are faster for checking membership. You can refer to others's answers on how to do that.
eg.

```
idxs = '{}[]'
for idx in tf:
    if idx in idxs:
        continue
    else:
        mk += idx
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find more readable names as there is no sample data, so I keep them untouched.

You could probably nest these two `for` loops together, to get even less lines, but poor readability IMHO.

```py
def jsonToCsvPart1(fields):
    csvFormats = []
    for tf in json.loads(fields):
        mk = ''.join(str(idx) for idx in tf if str(idx) not in '{}[]')
        csvFormats.append(mk)
    yield ','.join(csvFormats)
```