# How to do different concatenation for a multi-level dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary, concatenation

I have a multi-level dictionary called `mydict` that looks like the one bellow and I am trying to do a concatenation that gives me a different dataframe for each keys of the dict.

```py
mydict -> {agent_1: {step1: {...}, step2: {...}, step3: {...}}, ...}
```

I can do that with the following code but it means doing it by hand and I am working with large data.

```py
boo  = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict[agent_1]['step_1'])
boo1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict[agent_1]['step_2'])
boo2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict[agent_1]['step_3'])
boo3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict[agent_1]['step_4'])

boo_tot = pd.concat([boo, boo1, boo2, boo3])
```

Also I have troubles automatizing this because the number of `step` parameter is not the same for each `key` of `mydict`.
As an example, let's say `agent_1` has 4 steps while `agent_2` only has 3.
I tried following what was given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary) stackoverflow accepted answer but it does not apply to my situation.

As you can see bellow, this method gives me one dataframe and all the values for each `step` (= `etape` in the df bellow) are in one row each time whereas I would like a different dataframe for each `agent` with `pcc`, `time`, `route_type` and `mode` as columns and their values printed on row under the other for each `step`

[image]

This is what I was hoping to get instead:

```py
For agent_1:

    mode    pcc     time    route_type  etape    id
0   TC      data1   time1   data1       etape_0  NaN
1   TC      data2   time2   data2       etape_0  NaN
2   TC      data3   time3   data3       etape_0  NaN
3   TC      data4   time4   data4       etape_0  NaN
... ...     ...     ...     ...         ...      ...
16  MAP     data16  time16  data16      etape_1  NaN
17  MAP     data17  time17  data17      etape_1  NaN
18  MAP     data18  time18  data18      etape_1  NaN
19  MAP     data19  time19  data19      etape_1  NaN
... ...     ...     ...     ...         ...      ...

And then I'd get a second dataframe for agent_2, a third for agent_3 etc.
```

I couldn't find a way to get what I want and unfortunately my vocabulary about this subject is very limited since I don't use multi-level dicts often. Any tips on the matter would be a huge help.