# 'dict of list of dict' to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict of list of dict

```
{
'Col1Name': [{'date': '2020', 'value': '1111'},
             {'date': '2019', 'value': '2222'},
             {'date': '2018', 'value': '3333'}],
'Col2Name': [{'date': '2020', 'value': '777'},
             {'date': '2018', 'value': '999'}]
}
```

How can I import it elegantly into a dataframe, bearing in mind there may be missing values?

The end result should look something like: (or transposed, doesnt matter)

```
            2020      2019       2018
Col1Name    1111      2222       3333 
Col2Name     777       nan        999
```

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/13581730/14310038 Reply if you find it helpful or not

Comment: I think you need to write a custom function for it since you are using `date` as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `pandas.concat` and a small comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat({c: pd.DataFrame(l).set_index('date').T
           for c,l in d.items()}).droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
date      2020  2019  2018
Col1Name  1111  2222  3333
Col2Name   777   NaN   999
```

Input:

```
d = {
'Col1Name': [{'date': '2020', 'value': '1111'},
             {'date': '2019', 'value': '2222'},
             {'date': '2018', 'value': '3333'}],
'Col2Name': [{'date': '2020', 'value': '777'},
             {'date': '2018', 'value': '999'}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dictionary `d` we can use a comprehension to get the dictionary into an appropriate format, then pass to [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {k: {v['date']: v['value'] for v in lst} for k, lst in d.items()},
    orient='index'
)
```

`df`:

```
          2020  2019  2018
Col1Name  1111  2222  3333
Col2Name   777   NaN   999
```

We can remove `orient='index'` if wanting the other way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {k: {v['date']: v['value'] for v in lst} for k, lst in d.items()}
)
```

`df`:

```
     Col1Name Col2Name
2020     1111      777
2019     2222      NaN
2018     3333      999
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'Col1Name': [{'date': '2020', 'value': '1111'},
                 {'date': '2019', 'value': '2222'},
                 {'date': '2018', 'value': '3333'}],
    'Col2Name': [{'date': '2020', 'value': '777'},
                 {'date': '2018', 'value': '999'}]
}
```