# Construct a pandas DataFrame from items in a nested dictionary with lists as inner values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary `annot_dict` with structure:

- key = long unique string
- value = list of dictionaries

The values, the list of dictionaries, each have structure:

- key = long unique string (a subcategory of the upper dictionary's key)
- value = list of five string items

An example of the entire structure is:

```
annot_dict['ID_string'] = [
     {'ID_string': ['attr1a', 'attr1b', 'attr1c', 'attr1d', 'attr1e']},
     {'string2'  : ['attr2a', 'attr2b', 'attr2c', 'attr2d', 'attr2e']},
     {'string3'  : ['attr3a', 'attr3b', 'attr3c', 'attr3d', 'attr3e']},
             ]
```

The `ID_string` is the same as the first sub-dictionary key. This is the output of a gff3 file parser function I wrote and the real dictionary information is the genes (`ID_string`) and transcripts (`string2`, `string3`,...) from the genome of human chromosome 9, if anyone is familiar with the structure of that file type. The attribute lists describe biotype, start index, end index, strand, and description.

I want to put this information into a pandas DataFrame now. I want to loop through the outermost keys (the `ID_string`s) in the dict to make one big DataFrame containing a row for each `ID_string` and rows for each of its subcategories underneath it (`string2`, `string3`).

I want it to look like this:

```
| subunit_ID |  gene_ID  | start_index | end_index | strand |biotype | desc   |
|------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
|'ID_string' |'ID_string'|  'attr1a'   | 'attr1b'  |'attr1c'|'attr1d'|'attr1e'|
| 'string2'  |'ID_string'|  'attr2a'   | 'attr2b'  |'attr2c'|'attr2d'|'attr2e'|
| 'string3'  |'ID_string'|  'attr3a'   | 'attr3b'  |'attr3c'|'attr3d'|'attr3e'|
```

I did look at [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary) but none had quite the same dict structure as I do. This is my first question on SO so please feel free to improve the understandability of my question.

Comment: How 'subunit_ID', 'gene_ID', 'start_index', 'end_index', 'strand', 'biotype', 'desc' will be provided? How the 'gene_ID' is filled? What did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(
    (
        [subkey, key] + value
        for key, records in annot_dict.items()
        for record in records
        for subkey, value in record.items()
    ),
    columns=[
        'subunit_ID', 'gene_ID', 'start_index', 'end_index', 'strand','biotype', 'desc'
    ]
)
```

Result for

```
annot_dict = {
    'ID_string1': [
        {'ID_string1': ['attr11a', 'attr11b', 'attr11c', 'attr11d', 'attr11e']},
        {'string12'  : ['attr12a', 'attr12b', 'attr12c', 'attr12d', 'attr12e']},
        {'string13'  : ['attr13a', 'attr13b', 'attr13c', 'attr13d', 'attr13e']},
    ],
    'ID_string2': [
        {'ID_string2': ['attr21a', 'attr21b', 'attr21c', 'attr21d', 'attr21e']},
        {'string22'  : ['attr22a', 'attr22b', 'attr22c', 'attr22d', 'attr22e']},
        {'string23'  : ['attr23a', 'attr23b', 'attr23c', 'attr23d', 'attr23e']},
    ]
}
```

is

```
   subunit_ID     gene_ID start_index end_index   strand  biotype     desc
0  ID_string1  ID_string1     attr11a   attr11b  attr11c  attr11d  attr11e
1    string12  ID_string1     attr12a   attr12b  attr12c  attr12d  attr12e
2    string13  ID_string1     attr13a   attr13b  attr13c  attr13d  attr13e
3  ID_string2  ID_string2     attr21a   attr21b  attr21c  attr21d  attr21e
4    string22  ID_string2     attr22a   attr22b  attr22c  attr22d  attr22e
5    string23  ID_string2     attr23a   attr23b  attr23c  attr23d  attr23e
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Timus

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension to flatten the dicts to lists that include the dict keys as items, then load it to pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

annot_dict = {}
annot_dict['ID_string'] = [
     {'ID_string': ['attr1a', 'attr1b', 'attr1c', 'attr1d', 'attr1e']},
     {'string2'  : ['attr2a', 'attr2b', 'attr2c', 'attr2d', 'attr2e']},
     {'string3'  : ['attr3a', 'attr3b', 'attr3c', 'attr3d', 'attr3e']},
             ]

df = pd.DataFrame([[k]+list(annot_dict['ID_string'][0].keys())+v for i in annot_dict['ID_string'] for k, v in i.items()], columns=['subunit_ID','gene_ID','start_index','end_index','strand','biotype','desc'])
```

output:

|  | subunit_ID | gene_ID | start_index | end_index | strand | biotype | desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ID_string | ID_string | attr1a | attr1b | attr1c | attr1d | attr1e |
| 1 | string2 | ID_string | attr2a | attr2b | attr2c | attr2d | attr2e |
| 2 | string3 | ID_string | attr3a | attr3b | attr3c | attr3d | attr3e |