# create a dataframe from a dictionary using the keys as a new column?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary I'm trying to turn into a dataframe. The dictionary is essentially nested, where the keys need to be the column. For instance:

```
{
"apple":[
{
"price":19,
"store":"xyz"},
{"price":13,
"store":"abc"
}
}],
"pear":[{
"price":25,
"store":"xyz"
}]
}
```

I'd like the final dataframe to be in the format of

```
FRUIT   PRICE   STORE
apple   19      xyz
apple   13      abc
pear    25      xyz
```

I'm trying to sort through the list by doing some type of a iteration through the 'fruit' keys like such

```
for fruit in fruit_dict.keys():
    df['FRUIT']=fruit
```

and then using pd.normalize to get the price/store, but this feels incredibly convoluted to me. Is there an easier or better way to get this dictionary 'flattened' down?

Comment: the provided dictionary is not valid python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension for list of dictionaries with concat helper dict for `FRUIT` column by keys of outer input dicts:

```
fruit_dict = {
"apple": [{
        "price": 19,
        "store": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "price": 13,
        "store": "abc"
    }
],
"pear": [{
    "price": 25,
    "store": "xyz"
}]}
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{**{'FRUIT':k}, **x} for k, v in fruit_dict.items() for x in v])
print (df)
   FRUIT  price store
0  apple     19   xyz
1  apple     13   abc
2   pear     25   xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

If the desired shape of the final df is (6,1) instead of (3,3) then you could use this

```
fruits = []
details = []
for fruit,detail in fruits_dict.items():
    for x in detail:
        details.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Details':x}))
        fruits.append(fruit)
final = pd.concat(details,keys=fruits)
```

Also refer to this for a similar question : [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)