# create dataframe in pandas using multilevel dict dynamic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am fetching api and trying that response into csv but on catch is there this is multilevel dict or json when i am converting into csv most of the look like list of dict or dicts
I am trying using this

```
def expand(data):
    d = pd.Series(data)
    t = d.index
    for i in t:
        if type(d[i]) in (list,dict):
            expend_s = pd.Series(d[i])
            t.append(expend_s.index)
            d = d.append(expend_s)
            d = d.drop([i])
    return d
df['person'].apply(expand)
```

[image: multidict column]
but this solution is not working. if we see person col there is multiple dict or list of dict like

```
        "birthDate": "0000-00-00",
        "genderCode": {
            "codeValue": "M",
            "shortName": "Male",
            "longName": "Male"
        },
        "maritalStatusCode": {
            "codeValue": "M",
            "shortName": "Married"
        },
        "disabledIndicator": False,
        "preferredName": {},
        "ethnicityCode": {
            "codeValue": "4",
            "shortName": "4",
            "longName": "Not Hispanic or Latino"
        },
        "raceCode": {
            "identificationMethodCode": {},
            "codeValue": "1",
            "shortName": "White",
            "longName": "White"
        },
        "militaryClassificationCodes": [],
        "governmentIDs": [
            {
                "itemID": "9200037107708_4385",
                "idValue": "XXX-XX-XXXX",
                "nameCode": {
                    "codeValue": "SSN",
                    "longName": "Social Security Number"
                },
                "countryCode": "US"
            }
        ],
        "legalName": {
            "givenName": "Jack",
            "middleName": "C",
            "familyName1": "Abele",
            "formattedName": "Abele, Jack C"
        },
        "legalAddress": {
            "nameCode": {
                "codeValue": "Personal Address 1",
                "shortName": "Personal Address 1",
                "longName": "Personal Address 1"
            },
            "lineOne": "1932 Keswick Lane",
            "cityName": "Concord",
            "countrySubdivisionLevel1": {
                "subdivisionType": "StateTerritory",
                "codeValue": "CA",
                "shortName": "California"
            },
            "countryCode": "US",
            "postalCode": "94518"
        },
        "communication": {
            "mobiles": [
                {
                    "itemID": "9200037107708_4389",
                    "nameCode": {
                        "codeValue": "Personal Cell",
                        "shortName": "Personal Cell"
                    },
                    "countryDialing": "1",
                    "areaDialing": "925",
                    "dialNumber": "6860589",
                    "access": "1",
                    "formattedNumber": "(925) 686-0589"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

your suggestion and advice would be so helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can solve multiple dict using  read as pd.josn_normalise and list of dict using the below functions first we get those columns which have list

```
def df_list_and_dict_col(explode_df: pd.DataFrame, primary_key: str,
    col_name: str, folder: str) -> pd.DataFrame:

    """ convert list of dict or list of into clean dataframe
    Keyword arguments:
    -----------------
    dict: explode_df --  dataframe where we have to expand column
    dict: col_name   --  main_file name where most of data is present

    Return: pd.DataFrame
    return clean or expand dataframe
    """
    explode_df[col_name] = explode_df[col_name].replace('', '[]', regex=True)

    explode_df[col_name] = explode_df[col_name].fillna('[]')
    explode_df[col_name] = explode_df[col_name].astype(
        'string')  # to make sure that entire column is string
    explode_df[col_name] = explode_df[col_name].apply(ast.literal_eval)
    explode_df = explode_df.explode(col_name)
    explode_df = explode_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    normalized_df = pd.json_normalize(explode_df[col_name])
    explode_df = explode_df.join(
        other=normalized_df,
        lsuffix="_left",
        rsuffix="_right"
    )
    explode_df = explode_df.drop(columns=col_name)

    type_df = explode_df.applymap(type)
    col_list = []
    for col in type_df.columns:
        if (type_df[col]==type([])).any():
            col_list.append(col)
    # print(col_list,explode_df.columns)
    if len(col_list) != 0:
        for col in col_list:
            df_list_and_dict_col(explode_df[[primary_key,col]], primary_key,
            col, folder)
            explode_df.drop(columns=col, inplace =True)
    print(f'{col}.csv is done')
    explode_df.to_csv(f'{folder}/{col_name}.csv')
```

first we get list col and pass col to function one by one and then check is there any list inside col and then go on and save into csv

```
type_df = df.applymap(type)
col_list =[]
for col in  type_df.columns:
  if (type_df[col]==type([])).any():
       col_list.append(col)
for col in col_list:
       # print(col, df[['associateOID',col]])
       df_list_and_dict_col(df[['primary_key',col]].copy(), 'primary_key', col,folder='worker')
       df.drop(columns=col, inplace=True)
```

now you have multiple csv in normalise format