# How to convert a 5-level dictionary into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary with structure:

**Level 1:**

- id (int)
- username (str)
- meta (contain a string of Kpi_info)

This is a dictionary:

```
dict = {'id': 206, 'username': 'hantran','meta': '{"kpi_info":\
            {"2021" :{"1":{"revenue":"2000", "kpi":"2100","result":"0"}, "2":{"revenue":"2500", "kpi":"2000", "result":"1"}},\
            "2022": {"1":{"revenue":"3000", "kpi":"2500","result":"1"}, "2":{"revenue":"2500", "kpi":"3000", "result":"0"}}}'
        }
```

My desire result is a DataFame like this:

| id | username | Year | Month | revenue | kpi | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 206 | hantran | 2021 | 1 | 2000 | 2100 | 0 |
| 206 | hantran | 2021 | 2 | 2500 | 2000 | 1 |
| 206 | hantran | 2022 | 1 | 3000 | 2500 | 1 |
| 206 | hantran | 2022 | 2 | 2500 | 3000 | 0 |

Apparently, similar question has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary). However, the solution only work for 3-level dictionary. I don't know how to make it work for my 1-level dictionary with most of the needed information is in a string.

Comment: Is the value in `meta` a dictionary or really a string which looks like a dictionary?

Comment: it is "a string which looks like a dictionary"

Comment: The solution in the question you linked extends fairly simply to a dictionary of any level - What have you tried yourself to modify that code to extend to your case? What have you done to convert the string that contains the representation of a dictionary to a dictionary? Unless you can be more specific about your problem, your question should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Grismar oh, it seems that I have asked the wrong question. Thank you for pointing it out. I have modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* the string in your dictionary is valid json, it can easily be converted into a dictionary:

```
from json import loads

d = {'id': 206, 'username': 'hantran', 'meta': '{"kpi_info": {"2021" :{"1":{"revenue":"2000", "kpi":"2100","result":"0"}, "2":{"revenue":"2500", "kpi":"2000", "result":"1"}}, "2022": {"1":{"revenue":"3000", "kpi":"2500","result":"1"}, "2":{"revenue":"2500", "kpi":"3000", "result":"0"}}}}'}

d['meta'] = loads(d['meta'])
```

However, the representation of the dictionary in your code is not a valid dictionary, as it is missing a closing `}`. There's no easy way to deal with errors like these, so you should check if your actual data has this problem, or whether you should check the code you share more carefully.

Note that you shouldn't call a dictionary `dict`, since doing so will *shadow* the actual `dict` type and you won't be able to access that normally after doing so.

With the dictionary `d` it's now fairly easy to construct a DataFrame as needed:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame([
    {
        'id': d['id'], 'username': d['username'],
        'year': int(k1), 'month': int(k2),
        'revenue': d2['revenue'], 'kpi': d2['kpi'], 'result': d2['result']
    }
    for k1, d1 in d['meta']['kpi_info'].items()
    for k2, d2 in d1.items()
])

print(df)
```

This makes use of `pandas` ability to turn a list of dictionaries into a dataframe, using the keys of the dictionaries as column references.

Result:

```
    id username  year  month revenue   kpi result
0  206  hantran  2021      1    2000  2100      0
1  206  hantran  2021      2    2500  2000      1
2  206  hantran  2022      1    3000  2500      1
3  206  hantran  2022      2    2500  3000      0
```