# How to convert multilevel json/dict into python dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am getting output web api response as below.

```
d = { 'L1': [{'att_1': 10, 'att_2': 'whatever',
                  'att_4': 214, 'att_5': 'YES'}],
  'L2': [{'att_1': 11, 'att_2': 'whatever News',
                  'att_4': 230, 'att_5': 'another'}],
  'L3': [{'att_1': 12, 'att_2': 'whatever says',
                  'att_4': 213, 'att_5': 'YES'}]}
```

from  above multilevel json/dict i need pandas data frame as below.

```
      att_1    att_2           att_4     att_5
L1    10       whatever        214       YES
L2    11       whatever  News  230       another
L3    12       whatever says   213       YES
```

I tried as below

```
for k, v in d.items():
   print(k)
   print(v)

pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k:(v,orient='index') for k, v in d.items()}axis=1)
```

I am getting error. could you pls provide the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)

Comment: No. Finally I achieved using jsonnormalize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general solution create DataFrames in dictionary comprehension with  [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last remove second level of MultiIndex by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in d.items()}).droplevel(1)
print (df)
    att_1          att_2  att_4    att_5
L1     10       whatever    214      YES
L2     11  whatever News    230  another
L3     12  whatever says    213      YES
```

If there are one element lists is possible use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v[0] for k, v in d.items()}, orient='index')
print (df)
    att_1          att_2  att_4    att_5
L1     10       whatever    214      YES
L2     11  whatever News    230  another
L3     12  whatever says    213      YES
```

Comment: What's the difference between OP's question and the one in my comment?

Comment: The above one is working with uneven length

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the *typos* in your `d` (`'Lx'` instead of `Lx`), you can *re-arange/fix* your code this way :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v[0] for k, v in d.items()}, orient="index")
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

    att_1          att_2  att_4    att_5
L1     10       whatever    214      YES
L2     11  whatever News    230  another
L3     12  whatever says    213      YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records((v[0] for v in d.values()), index=d.keys())

+--+-----+-------------+-----+-------+
|  |att_1|att_2        |att_4|att_5  |
+--+-----+-------------+-----+-------+
|L1|10   |whatever     |214  |YES    |
|L2|11   |whatever News|230  |another|
|L3|12   |whatever says|213  |YES    |
+--+-----+-------------+-----+-------+
```