# How can I use the key and the value from a dictionary in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df.head())

Line                        values
Line1                       {'ValueType1': 1}
Line2                       {'ValueType2': 3}
Line3                       {'ValueType3': 5, 'ValueType4': 6}
```

I want to have the following dataframe at the end:

```
Line                        Valuetype          value
Line1                       ValueType1         1
Line2                       ValueType2         3
Line3                       ValueType3         5
Line3                       ValueType4         6
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `json_normalize` to convert the dictionaries to columns
2. `join` to the original DataFrame and `drop` unnecessary columns
3. `melt` the dataframe to unpivot from wide to long
4. `dropna` and `reset_index` to get the output

```
>>> (df.join(pd.json_normalize(df["values"]))
       .drop("values", axis=1)
       .melt(id_vars="Line")
       .dropna()
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       )

    Line   Valuetype  value
0  Line1  ValueType1    1.0
1  Line2  ValueType2    3.0
2  Line3  ValueType3    5.0
3  Line3  ValueType4    6.0
```